# search through word files, find text, copy into excel

Tags: excel, vba

I'm trying to have VBA loop through the word files that I choose in the file picker, find each instance of the string I'm specifying using Selection.Find, and then copy/paste all of the strings into an excel spreadsheet separated by the filename of the word file they came from (See attached). At the below link I have three example word files that the text will be coming from, as well as an example of what the spreadsheet needs to look like on output. My current code is below:

**EDIT:
Updated the code so that it's no longer missing results that should be picked up. Currently the biggest issue is that in the case where there are many results, it provides duplicate output for the final one. If there is only one result, it always provides duplicate output. Obviously I can clean this up afterwards in excel but it would be nice to get it right in the code.

https://www.dropbox.com/sh/id5af9la0rixcjm/AAD3FULpEjDp4o-5kZvXWtMsa?dl=0

```
Sub Search_and_Replace()

' 500 files is the maximum applying this code
Dim MyDialog As FileDialog, GetStr(1 To 500) As String
Dim iCount As Integer
Dim xlrow As Integer
Dim oData   As New DataObject 'object to use the clipboard
'Note: This code must be run from a file outside the directory of files you are trying to change, otherwise it won't loop properly.
'Open up any word file outside the directory of files you want to change. Create a new module in the template, paste in this code and change the .text and .replacement.text fields in the appropriate section, then click run.

On Error Resume Next




Set MyDialog = Application.FileDialog(msoFileDialogFilePicker)

' ---------------------------------------------------------------
' *.doc? allows processing of *.doc and *.docx files.
' ---------------------------------------------------------------
With MyDialog
.Filters.Clear
.Filters.Add "All WORD File ", "*.doc?", 1
.AllowMultiSelect = True

i = 1
If .Show = -1 Then
For Each stiSelectedItem In .SelectedItems
GetStr(i) = stiSelectedItem
i = i + 1
Next

i = i - 1
End If

Application.ScreenUpdating = False


'-------------------------------
'EXCEL
Application.DisplayAlerts = False
Dim xl
Dim wb, ws, xlr
Set xl = CreateObject("Excel.Application")
xl.Visible = True
xl.SaveAs Filename:="C:\Users\mattm\OneDrive\Desktop\NUMBERED\tooltable.xlsx"
Set wb = xl.workbooks.Add
Set ws = wb.worksheets(1)
'Set xlr = ws.Range("a1")
Application.DisplayAlerts = True

'--------------------------------






For j = 1 To i Step 1
Set Doc = Documents.Open(FileName:=GetStr(j), Visible:=True)
Dim pathname as String
pathname = Dir(GetStr(j))
Dim fileID as String
fileID = Left(pathname,8)



 '-------------------------------------------------------
 'Beginning of Body Updates
 '-------------------------------------------------------
Windows(GetStr(j)).Activate
Selection.Find.ClearFormatting
Selection.Find.Replacement.ClearFormatting



With Selection.Find
    .Text = "09000070??T????" ' Find What
    .Forward = True
    .Wrap = wdFindStop
    .Format = False
    .MatchCase = False
    .MatchWholeWord = False
    .MatchByte = True
    .MatchWildcards = True
    .MatchSoundsLike = False
    .MatchAllWordForms = False
    .Execute
End With

Selection.Copy




Workbooks("tooltable.xlsx").Activate
    Range("A:A").NumberFormat = "@"
    ActiveCell.Value = fileID
    ActiveCell.Offset(0,1).Select
    ActiveCell.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues
    ActiveCell.Offset(1,-1).Select

    oData.SetText text:=Empty 'Clear
    oData.PutInClipboard 'take in the clipboard to empty it




Windows(GetStr(j)).Activate






Do While Selection.Find.Found = True And iCount < 1000
        iCount = iCount + 1
        With Selection.Find
            .Text = "09000070??T????" ' Find What
            .Forward = True
            .Wrap = wdFindStop
            .Format = False
            .MatchCase = False
            .MatchWholeWord = False
            .MatchByte = True
            .MatchWildcards = True
            .MatchSoundsLike = False
            .MatchAllWordForms = False
            .Execute
        End With

        Selection.Copy
        Workbooks("tooltable.xlsx").Activate
    Range("A:A").NumberFormat = "@"
    ActiveCell.Value = fileID
    ActiveCell.Offset(0,1).Select
    ActiveCell.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues
    ActiveCell.Offset(1,-1).Select



    oData.SetText text:=Empty 'Clear
    oData.PutInClipboard 'take in the clipboard to empty it



Loop




ActiveDocument.Save
ActiveWindow.Close
' -------------------------------------------------------
' End of Body Updates
' -------------------------------------------------------
Next

Application.ScreenUpdating = True

End With

MsgBox "operation end, please view", vbInformation

End Sub
```

Comment: What's the specific problem you're having with your code?

Comment: just updated the post with that info